# Upvoting a comment sometimes display its score in the wrong color

Tags: bug, comments, comment-voting

These two comments have the same score, but the scores have a different "hotness" color:

[image: screenshot]

The upper comment I just upvoted. It displays correctly when I reload the page, though.

It looks like a CSS class isn't being applied here when the score is updated inline — this is the generated HTML of the score numbers in the above screenshot.

```html
<span class="" title="number of 'great comment' votes received">2</span>

<span class="cool" title="number of 'great comment' votes received">2</span>
```

Comment: While you may want to classify this as a bug, I hope it gets closed as "who cares?"

Comment: @AaronBertrand - just because it is small, doesn't mean it is insignificant. [little details matter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/05/this-is-all-your-app-is-a-collection-of-tiny-details.html)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Actually I want to know if it's intentional or a bug.

Comment: @Ephraim I can hardly tell the difference between those two colors, and I'm struggling to understand why it matters. As I said, I am not disputing that it is a "bug" I just think it is the opposite of high priority.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Huh. Well, you tell me what I should classify it as. The bug tag doesn't imply any sort of urgency or priority. I think there used to be a "minor issues" meta tag but it got burninated.

Comment: @lunboks I'm not saying you shouldn't have posted it or suggesting that it should be tagged differently. I just don't deem it worthy of actual effort on the devs' part. That is just my opinion.

Comment: `[status-whocares]`

Comment: @TheEstablishment ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Is that...a cat? Or...something else? (Also, I don't necessarily *agree* with that status. Just a humorous response to Aaron's comment.)